# How do I register a callback for a dismissableFrameLayout in Android?

Tags: java, android, wear-os

I'm trying to use [this layout component](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/wear/widget/DismissibleFrameLayout?hl=de).  I just don't know how to register a callback. I need to register the [onDismissFinished](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/wear/widget/DismissibleFrameLayout.Callback?hl=de#onDismissFinished(androidx.wear.widget.DismissibleFrameLayout)) callback but I'm at a loss.  I'm working in Java, Thanks.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of examples on github.

For example using viewBinding

https://github.com/joharei/nearby-mobility/blob/5e0244b4daeb0aac04c5dc661c7dde6c1769cf21/app/src/main/java/app/reitan/nearby_mobility/MainActivity.kt

```
        ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater).apply {
            setContentView(root)

            swipeDismissRootContainer.registerCallback(object :
                DismissibleFrameLayout.Callback() {
                override fun onDismissFinished(layout: DismissibleFrameLayout) {
                    // Hides view before exit to avoid stutter.
                    layout.visibility = View.GONE
                    finish()
                }
            })
```

https://github.com/search?q=DismissibleFrameLayout&type=code